# RXTX: conexão em porta serial de balança

Tags: java, serial

Estou tentando pegar o peso da balança, porém não estou conseguindo encontrar sucesso nessa batalha.

Conforme pode ser visto a conexão com a porta SERIAL (na verdade é USB) está tudo ok:

```
Stable Library
=========================================
Native lib Version = RXTX-2.1-7
Java lib Version = RXTX-2.1-7
```

Manual pode ser encontrado neste link: [manual](http://www.urano.com.br/suporte/manuais/portugues/1-50-302-218-Bal-UDC-CO-E.pdf), que diz:

> Protocolo usado: taxa 9600bps, 8 data bits, sem paridade, 2 stop bits.

As classes que estou utilizando são:

- `SerialCom`:

```java
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import java.util.Enumeration;

/**
 *
 * @author DexBook
 */
public class SerialCom {

    protected String[] portas;

    protected Enumeration listaDePortas;

    public SerialCom() {
        listaDePortas = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    }

    public String[] ObterPortas() {
        return portas;
    }

    protected String[] ListarPortas() {
        int i = 0;

        portas = new String[10];

        while (listaDePortas.hasMoreElements()) {

            CommPortIdentifier ips =

            (CommPortIdentifier) listaDePortas.nextElement();

            portas = ips.getName();

            i++;
        }

        return portas;
    }

    public boolean PortaExiste(String COMp) {
        String temp;

        boolean e = false;

        while (listaDePortas.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier ips = (CommPortIdentifier) listaDePortas.nextElement();

            temp = ips.getName();

            if (temp.equals(COMp) == true) {
                e = true;
            }

        }

        return e;
    }

}
```

- `SerialComLeitura`:

```java
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

/**
 *
 * @author DexBook
 */
public class SerialComLeitura implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener {

    public String Dadoslidos;

    public int nodeBytes;

    private int baudrate;

    private int timeout;

    private CommPortIdentifier cp;

    private SerialPort porta;

    private OutputStream saida;

    private InputStream entrada;

    private Thread threadLeitura;

    private boolean IDPortaOK;

    private boolean PortaOK;

    private boolean Leitura;

    private boolean Escrita;

    private String Porta;

    protected String peso;

    public void setPeso(String peso) {

        this.peso = peso;

    }

    public String getPeso() {
        return peso;
    }

    public SerialComLeitura(String p, int b, int t) {
        this.Porta = p;

        this.baudrate = b;

        this.timeout = t;
    }

    public void HabilitarEscrita() {
        Escrita = true;

        Leitura = false;
    }

    public void HabilitarLeitura() {
        Escrita = false;

        Leitura = true;
    }

    public void ObterIdDaPorta() {
        try {
            cp = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(Porta);

            if (cp == null) {

                System.out.println("Erro na porta");

                IDPortaOK = false;

                System.exit(1);

            }
            IDPortaOK = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro obtendo ID da porta: " + e);

            IDPortaOK = false;

            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void AbrirPorta() {
        try {
            porta = (SerialPort) cp.open("SerialComLeitura", timeout);

            PortaOK = true;

            // configurar parâmetros

            porta.setSerialPortParams(baudrate,

            porta.DATABITS_8, porta.STOPBITS_2, porta.PARITY_NONE);

            porta.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_NONE);

            System.out.println("Porta " + Porta + " aberta!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            PortaOK = false;

            System.out.println("Erro abrindo comunicação: " + e);

            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void LerDados() {
        if (Escrita == false) {
            try {
                entrada = porta.getInputStream();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Erro de stream: " + e);

                System.exit(1);
            }
            try {
                porta.addEventListener(this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Erro de listener: " + e);

                System.exit(1);
            }
            porta.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

            try {
                threadLeitura = new Thread(this);

                threadLeitura.start();

                run();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Erro de Thred: " + e);
            }
        }
    }

    public void EnviarUmaString(String msg) {
        if (Escrita == true) {
            try {
                saida = porta.getOutputStream();

                System.out.println("FLUXO OK!");
            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println("Erro.STATUS: " + e);
            }

            try {
                System.out.println("Enviando um byte para " + Porta);

                System.out.println("Enviando : " + msg);

                saida.write(msg.getBytes());

                Thread.sleep(100);

                saida.flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Houve um erro durante o envio. ");

                System.out.println("STATUS: " + e);

                System.exit(1);
            }
        } else {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro de Thred: " + e);
        }
    }

    // Essa procedure pode conter incompatibilidades, qualquer problema rever.

    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent ev) {
        StringBuffer bufferLeitura = new StringBuffer();

        int novoDado = 0;

        switch (ev.getEventType()) {

        case SerialPortEvent.BI:

        case SerialPortEvent.OE:

        case SerialPortEvent.FE:

        case SerialPortEvent.PE:

        case SerialPortEvent.CD:

        case SerialPortEvent.CTS:

        case SerialPortEvent.DSR:

        case SerialPortEvent.RI:

        case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:

            break;

        case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:

            // Novo algoritmo de leitura.

            while (novoDado != -1) {
                try {
                    novoDado = entrada.read();

                    if (novoDado == -1) {
                        break;
                    }

                    if ('\r' == (char) novoDado) {
                        bufferLeitura.append('\n');
                    } else {
                        bufferLeitura.append((char) novoDado);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.out.println("Erro de leitura serial: " + ioe);
                }

            }

            setPeso(new String(bufferLeitura));

            System.out.println("Peso: " + getPeso());

            break;
        }

    }

    public void FecharCom() {
        try {
            porta.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro fechando porta: " + e);

            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

    public String obterPorta() {
        return Porta;
    }

    public int obterBaudrate() {
        return baudrate;
    }

}
```

- `TCC_Serial`:

```java
public class TCC_Serial extends SerialCom {

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SerialComLeitura leitura = new SerialComLeitura("COM3", 9600, 500);

        // Iniciando leitura serial

        leitura.HabilitarEscrita();

        leitura.ObterIdDaPorta();

        leitura.AbrirPorta();

        leitura.EnviarUmaString("0x04");

        leitura.HabilitarLeitura();

        leitura.ObterIdDaPorta();

        leitura.LerDados();

        // Controle de tempo da leitura aberta na serial

        try {

            Thread.sleep(1000);

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

            System.out.println("Erro na Thread: " + ex);

        }

        leitura.FecharCom();

    }

}
```

No manual diz:

> enviando um caractere de comando(04 em hexadecimal).

Na classe `TCC_Serial` eu coloquei:

```
leitura.EnviarUmaString("04");

leitura.EnviarUmaString("4");

leitura.EnviarUmaString("0x04");
```

Quando eu executo o programa aparece:

```
Stable Library
=========================================
Native lib Version = RXTX-2.1-7
Java lib Version = RXTX-2.1-7
Porta COM3 aberta!
FLUXO OK!
Enviando um byte para COM3
Enviando : 0x04
```

Não dá erro, não dá nada, e não me retorna o peso da balança.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz? Pois realmente não imagino o que pode ser o 
problema.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
com java JSSC

SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3");
        try {
            System.out.println("Port opened: " + serialPort.openPort());
            System.out.println("Params setted: " + serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 2, 0));
            System.out.println("successfully writen to port: " + serialPort.writeBytes("0x04".getBytes()));
            byte[] buffer = serialPort.readBytes(46);//Read 10 bytes from serial port

```
        System.out.println(buffer.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(buffer[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("Port closed: " + serialPort.closePort());
    } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

Ele retorna

run:
COM3
Port opened: true
Params setted: true
successfully writen to port: true
46
112
-10
64
2
-120
-65
-58
1
-112
-65
-58
1
24
32
-93
20
-40
31
-93
20
0
-68
-58
1
0
0
0
0
-44
21
-28
111
20
0
0
0
-4
-10
64
2
32
-9
116
106
0
-68
Port closed: true

Comment: Você consegue se comunicar utilizando outro programa? Quais dos caracteres que você envia pra balança que fazem a mesma retornar o peso?

Comment: Parece-me que o seu problema está na forma de enviar o caractere hexadecimal de solicitação do peso (0x04). Vou dar uma olhada aqui e te dou um retorno.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, eu fiz um teste com a aplicação local, e a informação retorna.

Comment: Fiz a alteração conforme orientação, e continua nao retornando nada, e continua não dando erro. mais alguma ideia amigo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está ocorrendo, pois está sendo enviando uma conjunto de bytes para a balança que não corresponde ao caracter hexadecimal esperado.

Está sendo feito isso:

```
leitura.EnviarUmaString("0x04");
```

Dentro do método EnviarUmaString está acontecendo isso:

```
saida.write(msg.getBytes());
```

Onde **msg** é a mensagem passada como parametro e **saida** é um OutputStream.

Enfim, o que está sendo enviado são os bytes da string 0x04. Isso não é um hexadecimal. Basicamente, ao invés de enviar 1 byte conforme esperado, estão sendo enviados 4 bytes.

**para resolver faça assim:**

```
saida.write(new byte[]{0x04});
```

Comment: O problema relatado acima certamente era um dos problemas do código. Preciso analisar com mais detalhes para verificar outros. De qualquer maneira, voce consegue fazer a balança transmitir utilizando outro software?

Comment: Não sei o que você já tentou, mas geralmente eu isolo os problemas quando preciso tratar com esse tipo de situação. A 1a coisa que eu faria é testar a comunicação com a balança em outro software que eu tenha certeza que se comunica. No Windows vc pode usar o Hyperterminal, abra uma conexão com as especificações da balança e depois pressione CTRL-D. Isso deve produzir o caraceter 0x04. Se tudo estiver correto (cabo da balança + parametros), então você verá o peso no Hyperterminal. Caso voce não veja, não significa que exista um problema ainda, pois pode ser que o CTRL-D não tenha funcionado. 
,

Comment: Me confirme por favor 04 em hexadecimal é 04 ou 0x04, ou??? peguei a tabela ASC mas n vi diferença... testei em outro  software e funciono corretamente.... mais alguma dica?

Comment: @HimorriveL, sim é 04, mas a representação em Java de um Hex é utiliza 0x seguido do Hex. Por isso 04 em Java fica 0x04. Vc avançou bem, pois ao confirmar que funciona em outro software corretamente você isolou cabo de comunicação e algum possível problema na balança. Minha sugestão agora é a seguinte: Crie um simples programa em Java que apenas envia esses bytes para a balança. Um programa bem simples mesmo. Eu já integrei muitas balanças e tenho um programa em Java que comunica com uma delas. Eu não uso RXTX, mas JSSC. Embora RXTX é muito utilizado. Enfim, é um detalhe, acredite.

Comment: Novamente obrigado por estar querendo me ajudar. Então.... o que eu estou fazendo é o mais simples possível.... existe algo mais simples do que estou fazendo? a comunicação já está pronta, a única coisa que não está dando é a parte de enviar e receber e sinceramente eu já pesquisei na internet inteira e não consegui achar a solução..... sinceramente depois de tudo que pesquisei estou travado nesse ponto e eu realmente preciso de uma ajuda, pois não sei como prosseguir...

Comment: Uma outra opção é você tentar se comunicar utilizando o Processing (processing.org). É Java, muito simples de usar e creio que usa RXTX como a biblioteca pra comunicação serial. Faça um teste com ele.

Comment: EU fi um teste com o JSSC que você disse. porem continuo sem receber a informação final... coloquei 46 pois no manual diz que tem que ser 46... mais alguma dica??

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, também utilizo RXTX para comunicação e consigo sim extrair informação da balança hora retornando caracteres diferentes e hora retornando o peso.

Existe dois problemas que venho me deparando:

1º - Retorno de caracteres especiais: já verifiquei todos os dados de configuração como velocidade, paridade entre outros que pode ser a causa do erro mas estão todos corretos e hora retorna estes caracteres diferente.

2º - A balança tem de estar na configuração de envio intermitente de informação então ela vai ficar enviando o peso enquanto estiver aberta a comunicação com ela, como faço a extração do peso e parada da comunicação.

Comment: olá, o RXTX é muito chato para configurar pois depende de várias configurações para que o mesmo funcione, migrei para o JSSC e não me arrependi nenhum pouco. 1 - Quando estava testando tive problema de caracteres especiais, descobri depois que estava faltando fazer o retorno dos dados corretos. 2 - Você pode fazer de duas formas, crie um boolean true e colocar um while que enquanto tiver true, ele busca a informação da balanca... ou então vc da request, e pega a informação depois. Abraços

Comment: Concordo com o @HimorriveL. O RXTX é bem complicado para usar e configurar. Diferentemente, eu migrei para o Javino, que permite uma configuração bem simples de comunicação e da uma segurança no recebimento e envio de informações, já que usa duas bibliotecas e outra pro controlador. Vale deixar a dica também.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado @cantoni consegui graças as suas dicas...

caso alguem precise:

*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author DexBook
 */

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import jssc.SerialPort;

import jssc.SerialPortException;

import jssc.SerialPortList;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
    for (String portName : portNames) {
        System.out.println(portName);
    }

    SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3");
    try {
        System.out.println("Port opened: " + serialPort.openPort());
        System.out.println("Params setted: " + serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 2, 0));
        System.out.println("successfully writen to port: " + serialPort.writeBytes(new byte[]{0x04}));
        byte[] buffer = serialPort.readBytes(46);//Read 10 bytes from serial port
        System.out.println(new String(buffer));
        System.out.println("Port closed: " + serialPort.closePort());
    } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Olá, Himorrivel, se minha resposta te ajudou, sinta-se livre para aceitá-la como a correta.