# Conexão portal serial balança utilizando JSSC

Tags: java, serial, porta-serial, jssc

Faço comunicação com uma balança via porta serial, e hoje utilizo a biblioteca **`JSSC`** porém os retornos da balança hora são do peso e hora são de caracteres diferentes, pesquisando cheguei a conclusão de que pode alguma informação de configuração da porta que pode não estar legal, mas verifiquei as configurações que marca da balança sugere e fiz conforme o solicitado porém continua da mesma forma.

Segue o código para extrair a informação.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortException;
import jssc.SerialPortList;

public class Balanca {

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
    for (String portName : portNames) {
        System.out.println(portName);
    }

    SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");
    try {
        System.out.println("Port opened: " + serialPort.openPort());
        System.out.println("Params setted: " + serialPort.setParams(4800, 8, 1, 0));
        System.out.println("successfully writen to port: " + serialPort.writeBytes(new byte[]{0x04}));
        byte[] buffer = serialPort.readBytes(46);//Read 10 bytes from serial port
        System.out.println(new String(buffer));
        System.out.println("Port closed: " + serialPort.closePort());
    } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

}
}
```

E a saída que tenho é a seguinte.

Quando obtenho retorno de caracteres

```
COM1
Port opened: true
Params setted: true
successfully writen to port: true
 &��&ӐSӓӐSӓӐSӓӐSӓӐSӓӐS
Port closed: true
```

Quando obtenho retorno dos dados em numeros

```
COM1
Port opened: true
Params setted: true
successfully writen to port: true
60013600136001360013600136001360
Port closed: true
```

A comunicação que usei extrai de uma mesma resposta daqui do fórum.

[RXTX: conexão em porta serial de balança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81800/rxtx-conex%C3%A3o-em-porta-serial-de-balan%C3%A7a)

Comment: qual o modelo e marca da balança?

Comment: Amigo já consegui uma solução em breve coloco uma resposta.

Answer (score -1):

Já tentou modificar esta linha do seu código:

```
System.out.println("Params setted: " + serialPort.setParams(4800, 8, 1, 0));
```

Para:

```
System.out.println("Params setted: " + serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0));
```

Não sei bem a diferença mas para o Arduino utilizamos 9600 como taxa de dados em bits por segundo (baud) para a transmissão de dados em série.

Veja nestes links:

1. https://www.embarcados.com.br/arduino-comunicacao-serial/
2. https://www.arduino.cc/en/serial/begin